# How to write text output of a C# application to a text file

Tags: c#, text, wmi

So forgive me if this is a "newbie" question, but I a just beginning to teach myself C#, and I began messing around with WMI, and using the microsoft WMI generator, I made this, for the purpose of having something to analyze in regards to how it works. But, is there a way to get it to write the data to a text file?

Code:

```
using System;

    using System.Management;

    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WMISample
    {
        public class MyWMIQuery
        {

            public static void Main()
            {
                try
                {
                    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_BIOS instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("SerialNumber: {0}", queryObj["SerialNumber"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just redirect it via the command line, e.g. `program.exe > test.txt`?

Answer (score 3):

If you just wish to append text to a file:

```
File.AppendAllText("c:\file.txt", "some text");
```

If you specifically wish to pipe the console to a text file, you need to redirect the standard output of the console to a FileStream, as described here:

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.71).aspx

```
 Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
 FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Create);
 // First, save the standard output.
 TextWriter tmp = Console.Out;

 StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(fs1);
 Console.SetOut(sw1);
 Console.WriteLine("Hello file");

 Console.SetOut(tmp);
 Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

 sw1.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific using statement for writing to and from files, its system.IO (for input output) here is a link to a tutorial that properly explains the uses of all basic IO
http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If this is for logging purposes you could use Trace and a TextWriterTraceListener to write out to a file, it's pretty much exactly what it's intended for.